# Pytorch predict wrong with small batch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Have code:

```py
firstItem, first_y = dataset[0]
secondItem, second_y = dataset[4444]
thirdItem, third_y = dataset[55555]
 
print(f"expected: {[first_y, second_y, third_y]}")

X = firstItem.unsqueeze(0)
X = torch.cat((X, secondItem.unsqueeze(0)), 0)
X = torch.cat((X, thirdItem.unsqueeze(0)), 0).cuda()
 
 
with torch.no_grad():
    pred = model_ft(X)
    print(f"predicted: {pred.argmax(1).cpu().numpy()}")
```

I get 3 items from dataset and process them though model.

So output of that code:

```
expected: [0, 12, 89]
predicted: [ 0 12 89]
```

Everything is perfect! Expected is equal predicted values.

Now let me show magic that I don't understand. Instead of 3 items we process only 2.

```py
firstItem, first_y = dataset[0]
thirdItem, third_y = dataset[55555]
 
print(f"expected: {[first_y, third_y]}")

X = firstItem.unsqueeze(0)
X = torch.cat((X, thirdItem.unsqueeze(0)), 0).cuda()
 
 
with torch.no_grad():
    pred = model_ft(X)
    print(f"predicted: {pred.argmax(1).cpu().numpy()}")
```

and output:

```
expected: [0, 89]
predicted: [202  89]
```

I **don't understand** why in this case expected and predicted items are not the same. If we will precess only one value then result gonna be the same (wrong prediction)

**Solved!** Thanks @coder00! You need to turn model to evaluation mode by calling model_ft.eval()

Comment: make sure you call model_ft.eval() before prediction

Comment: when you changed it to 2, did you change any other hyperparameters?

Comment: @TonySirico no, only thing I changed is number of images

Comment: @coder00 Didn't know about it! Thank you. Now everything work fine even with only one image!

Comment: @coder00 Do you know why this happened?

Comment: I read about this function but different between train and test shouldn't be so big, same weights same result?

Comment: Some layers have different pattern(behavior) between predictions and training, for example dropout

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thanks @coder00! You need to turn model to evaluation mode by calling model_ft.eval()